# How to permanently save a variable (login information)

Tags: python, variables, passwords, save

I am trying to code a username and password system and was wondering if there was any way to save the variable so even when the code stops the username will work the next time.
I have not yet started coding it and was just wondering if this was possible. I saw a few things on saving it as a file but with no luck. Thanks!

I tried saving it as a file but, I don't want to manually add every username and password.

Comment: Thanks @kidcoolness. I have already tried something like what you are suggesting the problem is more about efficiency instead of having over 100 different files for each username and password maybe just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are look for *persistence*, there are different ways to do so, python-specific option is [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) which allows you to seamlessly store dict inside file, consider following simple phone-book example, let
`addphone.py` content be

```
import shelve
name = input('What is your name?')
phone = input('What is your phone number?')
with shelve.open('phones') as db:
    db[name] = phone
```

and `listphones.py` content be

```
import shelve
with shelve.open('phones') as db:
    for name, phone in db.items():
        print(name,'uses phone',phone)
```

If your requirements stipulates interoperatibility with other software, you might consider using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), you might also consider other [PersistenceTools](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PersistenceTools)

Answer (score 0):

You can try appending them to a file instead of writing a new one for each user. So each time a user logs in the creds will be saved to that file. This is what I have done in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can automaticly save everything in a simple text file.

```
file = open("Python.txt", "w")
```

make sure the .txt exists and check before running that you are actually running your python file in the right directory.
Then write the variable to the file and make a newline by appending \n.

```
file.write(str(yourVariable), "\n")
```

Dont forget to close your file afterwards!

```
file.close()
```

To acces this varibale afterwards open it again by doing:

```
f = open('Python.txt', 'r')
contents= f.read()
```

and convert it back to your old type of variable by doing something like:

```
int(contents)
#or
list(contents)
```